# How to query with multiple clauses arguments with SugarRecord & Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, sugarrecord

I want to filter my query results by 2 clauses but I'm not sure how to do it and I can't find clear explanations on how to do so. Below is what I've tried.

```
termList = SugarRecord.find(Term::class.java, "type = ? AND category = ?", "hcp, "+ parentCategoryId.toString())
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
val termList = SugarRecord.find(Term::class.java,
                "type = ? and category = ?", // where clause
                "hcp", parentCategoryId.toString()) // arguments
```

Also, you can use *Query Builder*:

```
val termList = Select.from(Term::class.java).where(
        Condition.prop("type").eq("hcp"), // type =(equals) ?
        Condition.prop("category").eq(parentCategoryId.toString())).list()
```

More info here: http://satyan.github.io/sugar/query.html